# Android drawer layout to start new activity without drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawer

I just want to start the following activities using the layout.Please help me and thanks in advance.

My xml and rest files are working pls just go through the java file and let me know the changes. `NavigationDrawer` appears but does not respond to the items selected it. Just displays the same page blank.

```
package com.example.myapp;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Within which the entire activity is enclosed`enter code here`
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

// ListView represents Navigation Drawer
private ListView mDrawerList;

// ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the
// action bar
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// Title of the action bar
private String mTitle = "";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = "EDU LEARN";
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

    // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("EDU LEARN");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.menus));

    // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Enabling Home button
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // Enabling Up navigation
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // Getting an array of rivers
            String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.menus);

            // Currently selected river
            mTitle = menuItems[position];

            // Creating a fragment object
            WebViewFragment rFragment = new WebViewFragment();

            // Passing selected item information to fragment
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("position", position);
            // data.putString("url", string(position));
            rFragment.setArguments(data);

            // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            // Creating a fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

            // Committing the transaction
            ft.commit();

            // Closing the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
    });
}

public void selectItem(int position) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
    case 0: {
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
        startActivity(j);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    case 5: {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    case 6: {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get any errors? Why do you have a selectItem method when you dont even use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get any errors? Every time you are just replacing the same fragment !

You should do something like this :

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

       selectItem(position);

   }
```

Comment: no i am not getting any error its just changing the header of drawer layout to selected item name

Comment: Did you try the above code? It should have worked

Comment: @Sanket Naik I dont think there is any problem in your selectItem() method.see updated answer.

Comment: sorry bro but not able to make it
can you pls implement it in code above and show me
thanks

Comment: thank you all its done                   

can u further guide to maintain the drawer on new activity

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling selectItem() method anywhere.And your mDrawerList is just replacing fragment.So call selectItem() method onItemCLick of your listview.
Do like this in your onItemClickListener :

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItemRight(position);
    }
```

Comment: please check the 

public void selectItem(int position) {

in that there is some problem